# Explicit Interface Property Emits CA1033

Tags: c#

I have an interface that in our project is typically implemented explicitly (not my rule) and we do not want to make the class sealed.

```
public interface IHostable
{
    IHost Host { get; set; }
}

IHost IHostable.Host
{
    get { return _host; }
    set { _host = value; }
}
private IHost _host;
```

This emitted warning CA1033 which recommended implementing a protected method that would be accessible by derived types so that we do not lose access to this value. The fact that the variable was private to begin with was an oversight, so I'm glad the analyzer emitted this warning... so with that in mind, I re-implemented it as:

```
    IHost IHostable.Host
    {
        get { return Host; }
        set { Host = value; }
    }

    private IHost _host;

    protected IHost Host
    {
        get { return _host; }
        set { _host = value; }
    }
```

However, running Code Analysis still emits the same warning CA1033. From looking at the documentation and what I could find via Google (which wasn't much), this should be taking care of the warning.

What is still wrong with this?

Comment: Warnings are not errors. You've taken care of the underlying issue (that the base class method would become inaccessible) so suppress the warning and move on.